# .htaccess to redirect a url but allow to download a file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

from a QR-Code I receive an URL like this http://www.example.com/upload/folder/filenamae.pdf

This pdf file is an image of a certificate and I need control in a mysql table if this certificate is active-suspended-revoked
To do this I add a rule in my htacces file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^upload/folder/([^/]+).pdf$   app_user.php?id=$1
```

and in app_user.php I read the code, search in table and give an output.

If the certificate is revoked nothing happens, only a message like "Cerificate revoked" is displayed, but for example if the certificate is suspended or active I need to allow the downlod of the file and on dispaly I have to read a message like "Cetificate active, click here to download".

But if I click on link, as there is the rule in htacces, again the same page opens.

How can I allow he download of the file?

Comment: You can serve the file from within the php via `file_get_contents()` and related functionality.  Read it, print appropriate headers, dump file contents.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thanks a lot @alzee `code 
$filename = $_GET['id'] .".pdf"; 
$path = "upload/folder/". $_GET['id'] .".pdf";
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$file_size = filesize($path);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Description: Download PHP");
header("Content-Length: $file_size");
echo $content;
`